# Is there a way to rename files in bulk by the name of their folder?

Tags: bash, powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script that goes into every folder in a certain directory, and every child with the parent.

Example:

```
Z:\Folder1\File.txt
Z:\Folder1\Picture.jpeg
Z:\Folder1\Data.csv


Z:\Folder2\File.txt
Z:\Folder2\Picture.jpeg
Z:\Folder2\Data.csv

=

Z:\Folder1\Folder1.txt
Z:\Folder1\Folder1.jpeg
Z:\Folder1\Folder1.csv

Z:\Folder2\Folder2.txt
Z:\Folder2\Folder2.jpeg
Z:\Folder2\Folder2.csv
```

I have this so far

```
dir | rename-item -NewName {$_.name -replace *,"Folder1"}
```

Please let me know how I can loop through every folder, and how I can rename them based on the folder name.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you're asking:

```
Get-ChildItem Z:\Folder* -Directory | Get-ChildItem -File | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.DirectoryName.split('\')[-1] + $_.Extension } -WhatIf
```

Adjust the folder name filter (.\Folder*) as required and remove the `-WhatIf` if you're satisfied with the changes it will make.

Obviously this doesn't account for where you might have a name clash if there are two files in the folder with the same extension. The following would do that:

```
$FilesToRename = Get-ChildItem Z:\Folder* -Directory | Get-ChildItem -File 

foreach ($FileToRename in $FilesToRename) {

    $NewName = $FileToRename.DirectoryName.split('\')[-1] + $FileToRename.Extension
    $NewFile = Join-Path $FileToRename.Directory $NewName

    $i = 0

    While (Test-Path $NewFile) {
        $i = $i++
        $NewName = $FileToRename.DirectoryName.split('\')[-1] + "[$i]" + $FileToRename.Extension
        $NewFile = Join-Path $FileToRename.Directory $NewName
    }

    $FileToRename | Rename-Item -NewName $NewName
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly for non-duplicate extensions, any ideas on how to deal with duplicates?

Comment: What would you want to happen if there's a duplicate? Skip it? Append a number?

Comment: A number would be just fine! :) Thanks for all the help